# How to allow integrations to work while in maintenance mode?

Tags: magento2.4, maintenance

My magento installation has integration with a ERP that uses multiple IPs to connect to it that keep changing. This makes it very difficult to develop the webshop in maintenance mode. How can I let magento 2.4 in maintenance mode while also allowing ERPs to perform their needed API calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable maintenance mode for IP `exempt IP-addresses enable disable` for using the below command.

Maintenance mode Enable List of exempt IP-addresses

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.3.26 --ip=192.0.4.27

Maintenance mode remove List of exempt IP-addresses

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable --ip=none

I hope this will help you.

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t. The ERP server IP doing the call keeps changing.

Comment: Furthermore I also explained in my question that I an IP-based maintenance mode is the problem. I didn’t mean that I wanted to add more IPs to the list, I meant that I need have something else than IP checks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a PHP env variable MAGE_REQUIRE_MAINTENANCE = null to bypass the maintenance assertion completely;

For more detail, please read `\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::assertMaintenance`